# Batch copy a folder to new folder in digitalocean space using go?

Tags: go, digital-ocean

I am trying to copy all contents within a folder in my digital ocean space to a new folder in the same space using GO. Currently, I am using s3Client.[ListObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.ListObjects) and then for each result doing s3Client.[CopyObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#S3.CopyObject). This works just fine, the issue with it is I will hit the space limits using this code if multiple people try to duplicate at the same time and have a lot of assets within the folder to copy over according to the [docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/)

> Spaces have the following request rate limits:
> 750 requests (any operation) per IP address per second to all Spaces on an account
> 150 PUTs, 150 DELETEs, 150 LISTs, and 240 other requests per second to any individual Space
> 2 COPYs per 5 minutes on any individual object in a Space

Any recommendations on where to go from here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your content? Also Implement their limitation to your batch copy program.

Comment: The content is images and video files. The site I am working on they create a project (which creates a folder in my DO space) and can upload custom images/videos to it (which are stored in the folder for their project in DO. There is no limit on how many files they can upload so they could have many large/small files